# How to retrieve records from another table?

Tags: cakephp

I'm quite new to CakePHP, I just baked a DB which contains:
 `employees, emp_skill` and `skill` tables.  I'm trying to create a drop-down list displaying role names when I create an employee record. I have `employee IDs` in employee table, `skill IDs` and `skill names` in skill table and **Skill ID** and `employee` ID in `emp_skill table`. How can I implement this? 
Million thanks in advance.

Comment: Can an employee have one skill (in which case you want a drop down, but you don't need your emp_skill join table)? Or Many (in which case you want checkboxes, and a join table)?

Comment: I think at this point of the time I'll just set one for each employee, but i'll change it later to many-to-many

Comment: You should start off by following conventions. emp_skill should be emp_skills, skill should be skills. Tables are plural, models are singular.